# Why can't G/Z(G) be nontrivial and cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In a previous question: [Prove that G is abelian if (G:H) is prime, where H is in Z(G)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194383/prove-that-g-is-abelian-if-gh-is-prime-where-h-is-in-zg?noredirect=1#comment4514823_2194383), I was directed to: [If H ≤ Z(G) ≤ G, where G is a finite group,Z(G) is its center, and (G:H) = p for some prime p, then G is abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899511/if-h-%E2%89%A4-zg-%E2%89%A4-g-where-g-is-a-finite-group-zg-is-its-center-and-gh-p-for/1899527)

Here, an answer states that "hence G/Z(G) is a group of prime order, hence G/Z(G) is nontrivial cyclic, which is impossible (well-known exercise)."

However, I'm unable to see why this is impossible.

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is $[G:Z(G)]=p$, then we know that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic.
Hence $G$ is abelian and $G=Z(G)$.
This means that $[G:Z(G)]=1$ which is a contradiction to the assumption.
So $[G:Z(G)]=p$ cannot be happened.